# iPhone SDK chart Core-Plot: How to keep the X axis and Y axis keep on the bottom and right whatever i scale how much

Tags: iphone, sdk, charts, core-plot

I am now creating a chart by using Core-plot in iphone sdk.

But i want the X-axis and Y-axis always stay on the bottom and right whatever how much did i enlarge or scale.

you can see what happened in the following picture , thank you:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: i was not able to draw the Y-Axis on right hand side can you please share the code for drawing the y-axis on right hand side.

Comment: What is the name of this plot ? Please let me know.. Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line

```
y.isFloatingAxis=YES;
```

x.isFloatingAxis=YES;

if still axis moving then set NO instead of YES

Comment: thx, it works, but now it can not show up the Title of the Y axis, like 820. 830. 840.......>.<

Comment: Is it i missing something else?

Comment: It don't allow me post photo in Comments>.<
but i am now can not show the value number in right hand side

Comment: Then you can just mail me on nilesh08.ec@gmail.com

Comment: I think you need to pad like this

Comment: barChart.paddingLeft = 50.0;
barChart.paddingTop = 10.0;
barChart.paddingRight = 10.0;
barChart.paddingBottom = 80.0;

Comment: i have another question , please see this link, thank you >.< 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819472/iphone-core-plot-chart-zoom-in-zoom-out-y-axis-bigger-y-axis-smaller